# Form Validation: when all forms are filled out properly my successful alert popup does not show

Tags: javascript, html

My Javascript code:

```
if (valid == false){
    alert(errmsg);
    return false;
}else {
    var success = "Name: "+fname+" "+lname+"\n"+
        "Email: "+email+"\n"+"Address: "+adr1+", "+adr2+","+
        adr3+" "+zip;
    alert(success);
}
```

all that pops up is a blank alert window.
any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.
I'm kinda new to this, let me know if you need clarifications

heres my html portion of the code

```
        <form id="contactInfo" action="">

    <p class="name">
        <span class="nameHead">Name</span>
        <br />
        First: 
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />
        Last:
        <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Email:
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="55" />
    <p class="address"> 
        <span class="addressHead">Address</span>
        <br />
        Street:<input type="text" name="street" id="adr1" />
        <br />
        City: <input type="text" name="city" id="adr2"/>
        <br />
        State:<input type="text" name="state" id="adr3" size="2" maxlength="2"/>
        <br />
        ZIP Code: <input type="text" name="zipCode" id="zip" size="10" maxlength="10"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit"  value="Submit" onclick="return  validate();"  />
        <input type="reset"  value="Reset" />
    </p>
</form>
```

if the user enters name, city, zip, and email wrong (searched for patterns) so my if statements look like this

```
    if (adr1 == ''){
    errmsg = errmsg + "Street address is blank\n";
    valid = false;
    focusA1.focus();
    focusA1.select();
}else if(adr1S == -1){
    errmsg = errmsg + "Street address should be in the form of digits followed by letters\n";
    valid = false;
    focusA1.focus();
    focusA1.select();
}
```

if valid ends up being false at the end of the function the errmsg shows up with what is wrong and focuses on that portion of the form. One thing problem i did end up running into is that whenever the page loaded the form would automatically submit. would it have anything to do with this?

```
    <body onload= "rotate()">

<img src="images/a.jpg" name="banner" class="banner" />
```

code for a rotating banner?

The way I have it set up is to show another alert for when all form fields are entered correctly and when i do enter them correctly no alert shows up

Comment: Step1: Check your Script console for any errors.

Comment: show how valid,errmsg and success are defined.

Comment: it is not clear where you are modifying `valid` variable.

Comment: post your html code part or more JS part where you are assigning this error message

Comment: is `errmsg` undefined?  Try replacing `errmsg` with "hello" and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your validation function try some thing like this

```
function validation()
{
var valid == true;

    if(cond1)
    {
    alert(cond1fails);
    valid=false;
    }

    if(cond2)
    {
    alert(cond2fails);
    valid=false;
    }

.... and so on on to all the conditions .....

// then in the last line
return valid;
}
```

try this it should simply work

Comment: I think you mean `if (!cond1) {/* condition 1 failed */}`.

Comment: yeah man whatever u want it like to be , i just want you to set the variable 'valid' accordingly , and return it in the end other than applying if-else condition on it in the end .